# Azure DevOps - Find pipelines with schedules

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, when trying to find all jobs with time based triggers, is there an alternative to examining them one by one using UI or CLI?

[image]

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Rest API to [list builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?reasonFilter=schedule&api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

After adding `reasonFilter=schedule` parameter, you will get all schedule triggered builds and information related to the builds such as definition ids.